# How to prevent the error "unable to allocate x.xx GiB for an array with shape (xx, xxx) and data type xxxxx" without restarting VS Code?

Tags: python, memory, memory-management, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

I am working with a lot of data in a jupyter notebook. From my research I understand that the memory (RAM/SWAP) is not sufficient to (temporarily) store my large dataframe which causes the code to exit with the error `unable to allocate x.xx GiB for an array with shape (xx, xxx) and data type xxxxx`.

However, if I then completely close VS Code or restart the kernel of my jupyter notebook, I do not get this error. I only get this error after I have been working/coding in jupyter notebook for a long time. I tried `del <variable names>`, but that does not actually free the memory. I then also tried `gc.collect()` but that still leads to the error.

I mainly need to run two cells in jupyter notebook. The first imports millions of rows out of excel. This cell takes about 1 hour. The second cell cleans the data. I want to keep my excel imports, because those take really long. Everything else can be deleted from memory and free up space such that the error does not occur without having to restart the kernel.

Comment: Perhaps perform the data cleaning once, and then save the cleaned file to desk. Loading from the cleaned file directly might save you some memory.

Comment: How would I do this?

Comment: write a script that loads the data into a dataframe/array - perform whatever cleaning you need to do - then save the cleaned dataframe/array to a csv/pickle/whatever on your desk. 
close your kernel, reopen it, and read from the cleaned file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, I used `pickling` to solve this issue.